# Xenomai: /dev/rtheap is missing

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use xenomai.I try to install on my pc.I read this page and did these steps->http://www.stanley.gatech.edu/skelly/uncategorized/installing-xenomai-on-ubuntu-12-04/#comment-3379

But I didn't change configuration options.I use ubuntu 12.04 and xenomai 2.5.5.2.When I run "sudo ./trivial-periodic", I get a message via "Xenomai: /dev/rtheap is missing" . Is it a problem,what should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193622/xenomai:-/dev/rtheap-is-missing/) by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2014-09-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2014-09-27**:
When you say you didn't change the options, do you mean that you used exactly the options on that page?

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2014-09-27**:
Also, is there a reason you're using Xenomai 2.5.5.2 instead of one of the newer versions?

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2014-09-27**:
I handled this problem. There are some spelling mistakes in the documentation. Thanks your commend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For solution, follow [this guide](http://xenomai.org/2014/06/building-debian-packages/)

There is a wrong thing in this documantation, don't forget resolve it!

/usr/src/xenomai-kernel-sources/scripts/prepare-kernel.sh --linux=. --adeos=../ipipe-core-3.10.32-x86-2.patch

not xenomai-kernel-sources,write  "xenomai-kernel-source". And the folder, is under usr/src, don't include some necessary files. So you should use prepare-kernel.sh from the xenomai-2.6.4 directory.

---

Originally posted by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) with karma: 83 on 2014-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2014-09-28**:
Ah that's nice, they didn't use to have that tutorial on the xenomai site. Also, if you run into other issues, I've got a bunch of additional notes here: http://jbohren.com/articles/xenomai-precise/#configure-the-kernel

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2014-09-28**:
ok. I installed xenomai and compiled the kernel. tthanks your answer.